# Fuzzy icons if you have a device pixel ratio > 1 but < 1.5

Tags: bug, design

For those unfamiliar with the concept:

> The device pixel ratio is the ratio between physical pixels and logical pixels. For instance, the iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S report a device pixel ratio of 2, because the physical linear resolution is double the logical linear resolution.
>
> - Physical resolution: 960 x 640
> - Logical resolution: 480 x 320
>
> (…)
>
> If you are stuck with bitmap images, to accommodate for many different device pixel ratios, you should use CSS Media Queries to provide different sets of resources for different groups of devices.

Source: *[what exactly is device pixel ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8785643/1419007)*. (From the answer by [Anders Tornblad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549471/anders-tornblad).)

---

Stack Overflow will currently use high-resolution icons (2× the normal size) for higher-resolution screens, but *only* if it detects a device pixel ratio of **1.5 or higher**:

[image: Part of the CSS where the device pixel ratio is used]

As my system is currently scaled to 125% (a device pixel ratio of 1.25), all icons and other images are blurry.

[image: Screenshot of a part of a Stack Overflow page to demonstrate the problem]

Can the CSS be changed so crisp images will be displayed even with a lower device pixel ratio than 1.5?

Comment: Now what if I zoom to 110%? Or 120%? Or 111%? We can't support every single zoom level out there. As far as I know, SE's stance is: We don't support non-standard zoom levels.

Comment: The developers have stated in the past that issues stemming from altering zoom settings in browsers are not supported. I wouldn't be suprised if altering zoom settings in the OS are going to be met with the same response.

Comment: @It's not a non-standard zoom option as far as Windows 10 is concerned; 125% is one of the [scaling options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLIOe.jpg) offered as an option in the screen settings menu (and the default on my system). (Screenshot is via Google because my system isn't in English.)

Comment: Non-standard meaning everything that's different than 100%.

Comment: @Cerbrus Systems with a scaling level of 150% and greater are supported, though, as I tried to make clear in my post. I guess I could have made that clearer.

Comment: How is this actually implemented? Are they just downscaling larger icons when a 150% zoom level is detected? If so, I don't see why you couldn't just do that same thing for all zoom levels >100%. That wouldn't require any extra logic or "support" for zoom levels.

Comment: I doubt "with a scaling level of 150% and greater are supported", I'm sure it just shakes out that way.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, that's exactly what's happening. For example, [these icons](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc) are used in the hot network questions list when the scaling factor is less than 1.5, but [these](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc) are used for displays with a device pixel ratio of >1.5 (e.g. Retina Macs). I've also updated my post to include an explanation of device pixel ratio for those unfamiliar with the concept.